# Logging in from IIS webserver to sql database

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis, database-connection, forms-authentication

I've got a problem that I just cannot get my head around.

I've developed a simple application using Visual Studio, just a few HTML pages and some web forms / asp pages that connects to a Ms SQL server, everything within our corporate virtual server environment. The users (Intranet) can access the web server just fine, but the application cannot connect to the database. The error message is telling that the user Domain\servername is not authorized (error SqlException (0x80131904). Which is logical, as there is no such user. There is a AD service account created that should be used to access the database, but I cannot find were I can change this IIS manager. And I'm not allowed to add specific user/pwd details in the server connection in web.config (that leads to error in the code). The server and database is only allowing windows authentication.

If I've left out information that is needed to assist, just let me know and I can try to add it. Note that I'm totally new in this area, and I think I've gotten myself into something far too complex. We've got no .NET developers within the company, and the persons working with AD, windows operations and DBAs just know their little pieces.

Please help me to stay sane :)

//Eva-Lotta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add your windows authentication settings to `web.config`.

See [Access SQL Server Using a Mapped Windows Domain User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xzyzb0f.aspx)

Comment: It works!! I have worked so long with this. It will be champagne here today :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the [Application Pool for the web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).

- Find the one for your site, right-click, Advanced settings.
- Go to Identity, choose your domain service account
- Check file permissions

Answer (score 0):

Or leave the App Pool Identity as-is and provision a login in SQL Server for the machine account of the web server.

Your DBA would run something like:

```
use TargetDatabase
create role ApplicationUser;
grant select, insert, update, delete, execute to ApplicationUser;
create login [Domain\servername$] from windows;
create user [Domain\servername$] for login [Domain\servername$];
alter role ApplicationUser add member [Domain\servername$];
```